# How to produce tombstone messages in apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-rest-proxy

I want to delete messages from topics using messages coming to the Confluent REST Proxy. I found information about tombstones, but I didn't find any use cases. Is there any way I can transmit a tombstone message over the http protocol? Perhaps there are other ways to delete messages?

I found several commands for Kafka Command Line, but they cannot be called from the outside.

Comment: Have you tried simply doing `"value": null` in the API request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka records cannot be deleted by any producer client

Tombstones are **new** events, and are used for compacted topics only. Otherwise, it's just a record with a non null key and a null value, which should be possible to just put `null` as the JSON payload for the record value...

It's up to the broker, not the REST Proxy Log cleaner to delete/compact any closed segments on disk

> command line... cannot be called from the outside.

Unclear what this means, but yes they can, unless you have some firewall policies that are specific to your network

Comment: And how to call clt from the outside? I found the necessary command - $ kafka-delete-records.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 \
  --offset-json-file delete-test.config

Comment: That command is correct. You just provide the necessary bootstrap server address. That's a networking question, not specific to Kafka

Comment: And how to understand that I have successfully sent a tombstone? For example, in the topic there is a message `key: 10 value:100`, I am sending a new `key:10 value:null`. I am using the UI for Kafka and just see a new empty message, although if I understood correctly, the tombstone should compress the desired message and put it in the queue for deletion.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I am creating a topic with compression. My goal is for the consumer to receive a message from the topic, check that it is valid, send a tombstone to this message, after which the message would be deleted (as I understand it, this is determined by the parameter `delete.retention.ms` )
I don't understand by what principle a tombstone is used - does it destroy a message with the same key?

Comment: Yes, only messages with the same key. There is no compression. It is called compaction. https://redpanda.com/guides/kafka-performance/kafka-log-compaction